# Why python numpy sum() is giving different value than +?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays with two rows each, using which I am trying to do some calculation. Last step in calculation is to sum. When I try to sum using `.sum()`, it gives one answer, and when I try to manually sum with `+` by explicitly indexing each row, it gives different answer:

```
>>> ad=[[0.,0.,0.,-0.91,0.34],[0.,0.,1.,0.93,0.65]]
>>> nad=np.array(ad)
>>> W=[[0.29,0.],[0.23,0.]]
>>> NW = np.array(W)
>>> (nad[:,4] * (nad[:,3] + 0.96 * NW[nad[:,2].astype(int)][0][0])).sum() #use sum() on row 0 and 1
0.5707160000000001
>>> (nad[0,4] * (nad[0,3] + 0.96 * NW[nad[0,2].astype(int)][0])) #calculate by explicitly indexing row 0
-0.21474400000000005
>>> (nad[1,4] * (nad[1,3] + 0.96 * NW[nad[1,2].astype(int)][0])) #calculate by explicitly indexing row 0
0.74802
>>> (nad[0,4] * (nad[0,3] + 0.96 * NW[nad[0,2].astype(int)][0])) +  (nad[1,4] * (nad[1,3] + 0.96 * NW[nad[1,2].astype(int)][0])) #calculate by explicitly indexing row 0 and row 1
0.533276
```

The difference (0.57071-0.533276) might look small, but it blows with iterative calculations. I feel both approaches should give same values, right? But then why they are giving different values? What my eyes are missing?

Even [manually doing sum](https://www.google.com/search?q=0.74802-0.21474400000000005) gives later answer (one with `+`). Is numpy `sum()` doing something else which I dont know?

Comment: Float arithmetics are not exact, as not every number can be represented as a float

Comment: `NW[nad[:,2].astype(int)][0][0]` isn't this picking the first row only? So it will be different to `NW[nad[1,2].astype(int)][0]`. What do you want to achieve with the `[0][0]`?

Comment: I think what you wanted was `(nad[:,4] * (nad[:,3] + 0.96 * NW[nad[:,2].astype(int)][:, 0])).sum()`

Comment: Yes @Dan , seems that `(nad[:,4] * (nad[:,3] + 0.96 * NW[nad[:,2].astype(int)][:, 0])).sum()` gives exact answer as `0.533276`. So ` NW[nad[1,2].astype(int)][0]=0.23` and `NW[nad[0,2].astype(int)][0]=0.29`. But with `[0][0]`, I was taking `0.23` in both cases, right? Also, `nad[:,3] + 0.96 * NW[nad[:,2].astype(int)][0]` gives `array([-0.6316,  0.93  ])`, but `nad[:,3] + 0.96 * NW[nad[:,2].astype(int)][0,0]` gives `array([-0.6316,  1.2084])`. Why is it so?